# VoiceOver and asynchronous UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, voiceover

In my app, I have an `UITableView` with asynchronous data loading : when the view controller is loaded I show a modal activity spinner and start the HTTP request. When it is completed I hide the spinner and execute `reloadData()` on my table view. I also return `response?.count ?? 0` as a number of rows to make sure that the list it initially empty when the data is not ready yet.

It works like a charm, but I have an issue with VoiceOver : when opening the view controller, VoiceOver goes into the table and says "empty list". When the data is loaded it goes to the last element of the table.

This behavior is not very optimal : I would like VoiceOver to not focus the table while it's empty (it doesn't need to focus the modal spinner since we already have a sound while loading) and then go to the first element when it's loaded.

How may I do that ?

Comment: It's not immediately clear what the problem is.  VoiceOVer focus control or what happens on ViewController load. You absolutely should not hide visible views from VoiceOver. The fact that there is a table there and that it's empty is important. Now, that being said, perhaps this shouldn't be shared the second the ViewController loads, and there are dynamic content concerns. You might be able to do something more sensible with focus initially... but it's difficult to understand your layout and your actual issue given your explanation... pics???

Comment: Well it's just an empty ViewController with a fullscreen UITableView. There is no point in saying that there is an empty list while it's loading because it's the only view in the controller, and we have a particular loading sound that we play everywhere in the app.

I understand that VoiceOver describes what appears on the screen but saying that there is an empty list while it's loading is not very relevant, and pollutes the experience.

Comment: If there is a list there, it should be accessible. If it's not relevant, why is it even on screen to begin with??? If you want to "not pollute the experience" hide the list from everyone until there is data there. Want to know what a polluted experience is?  A partially sighted user "seeing" a view on a viewcontroller, wanting more information on it, running their finger over the view expecting helpful feedback, but having had some well intentioned (but ultimately ignorant) developer hide that view from VoiceOver.  THAT is a polluted experience.

Comment: This is an app made for visually impaired people. The user will "see" a back screen with a loading spinner, then a list taking the whole screen. I don't want VoiceOver to say "empty list", I want it to say "loading"

Comment: Clearly it is an app for visually impaired people, we are talking accessibility and focus and all that :). There we go, so there is a loading screen taking up the whole screen. This loading screen should be modal. You made it sound like there was a loading spinner next to the list. Again, images help... But, what you want is to have your loading image be modal. Will show in code.

Comment: Yes I realize now that the question was not very clear. I will update it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set up your loading overlay screen as a modal view. Modal means that the things behind the view are not actionable (or focusable by VoiceOver).

```
//Instantiate a view controller with your loading spinner.
_modalDialogViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"ModalDialog" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
                       instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AccessibleSpinnerModal"];

//Make this view controller modal, meaning only things on this screen will be actionable/focusable.
_modalDialogViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
```

You may also then need to use accessibility notifications in either of these styles.

```
//Announce that content is loading directly 
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification, "Stuff is laoding");
```

Or

```
//Shift focus to the view in your modal that is sharing the status of the loading content.
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChanged, spinnerView);
```

This will cause focus to move to that view.

Comment: Can I achieve the same by using an `UIActivityIndicatorView` directly, without a storyboard ?

Comment: Yeah, you can set a spinner up next to an empty list, and let them both be focused :). Honestly, there are methods you can use just using accessibility APIs to hide things directly. But they are hacks, and lead to inaccessible solutions for other ATs. This is the correct solution, you should use it, adding an XIB with a spinner and doing it properly is minimal extra effort over the "least lines of code" solution, which is a ridiculous Accessibility API hack that I don't really want to share, when a "correct" non-hack solution is available and obviously the right choice.